# set div full width and fix

Tags: html, css

I want to set `div#divcontainerdata` to fit the full width of the screen using CSS.

My simplified HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftDiv2" style="width:300px;float: left;"></div>
    <div class="leftDiv1" style="width:300px;float: left;"></div>
    <div class="divcontainerdata"></div>
</div>
```

I would like the final product to look like this:

```
|              |                  |
| div:leftdiv1 | divcontainerdata |
|              |                  |
| div:leftdiv1 |                  |
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: thanks but i need left div as navigation bar is also 300px

Comment: can you tell us exactly what you need?

Comment: you want div 1 or div1 and 2 on left side?

Comment: yes div1 and div2 on left side and divcontainerdata is rest of size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `float: left; clear: left` to first two divs and then set `margin-left: 300px` for the third div.

```
.leftDiv1, .leftDiv2 {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

.divcontainerdata {
    margin-left: 300px; /* the width of the floated divs */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3163650)

Comment: So that it doesn't wrap below the floated divs.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jfpak/3/)

Also, **it's good practice to import a css file rather than use inline styling.** I've modified your code accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="leftDiv2">
        </div>
            <div class="leftDiv1">
        </div>
            <div class="divcontainerdata">
        </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 100px; /*optional*/
}

.leftDiv1 {
    background-color: red; /*optional*/
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

.leftDiv2 {
    background-color: blue; /*optional*/
    clear:left;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

.divcontainerdata {
    background-color: yellow; /*optional*/
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 300px; /*margin-left = width of leftDiv1, leftDiv2*/
}
```

​    ​

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>    
    #left {
    border: 1px solid #000000; /* Delete it */

    float: left;

    width: 300px;
    }

    #content {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
    <div id="left_1">
        Left 1
    </div>
    <div id="left_2">
        Left 2
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftDiv2">div:leftdiv1</div>
    <div class="leftDiv1">div:leftdiv1</div>
    <div class="divcontainerdata">divcontainerdata</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.leftDiv1, .leftDiv2{
    clear:left;
    width:300px;
    float: left;
    border:solid black 1px;
    margin:2px;
}
.divcontainerdata{
    border:solid black 1px;
    margin:2px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/cYp4T/).